# Get Exchange Rate by Date OR Latest Exchange Rate in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo-11

Odoo 11 Community Edition:

I want to get the exchange rate in my odoo model. I am getting it as: obj.currency_id.rate

However, it is not returning the latest rate that I have stored. It gets only the first stored rate.

How do I get the exchange rate by date?

Comment: Do you want to convert one type of currency to another in odoo ?

Comment: No. I want to pass another parameter of date and get the rate for a particular date